# WP query doesn't return the same as get_posts()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to repair a broken functionality of a wordpress site that uses The Events Calendar and basic `WP_Query` to display events.

Events Calendar supports recurring events. Problem is that the `WP_Query` returns only the parent event (next ocurences are set as children to the first event but they also have the same custom post type).

I've found out that WP Query returns only the parent events but `get_posts()` function with exactly the same arguments returns all the events I need.

Arguments array the website uses to find the events:

```
array(8) { 
["ignore_sticky_posts"]=> int(1) 
["post_type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "tribe_events" } 
["post_parent"]=> NULL 
["author"]=> NULL 
["posts_per_page"]=> int(-1) 
["offset"]=> int(0) 
["post__not_in"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(427) } 
["display"]=> string(7) "excerpt" }
```

This code is somewhere really deep in another plugin so I don't have a lot of other options than alter the behavior of `WP_Query`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please follow the [basic debugging process in WordPress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info), and let us know the debug log.

Comment: You have a bad `posts_*` filter in your theme or in a plugin. Try setting `'suppress_filters' => true,` in your `WP_Query` and check if it solves the issue, if it does, you need to look for a `posts_*` filter that is badly coded

Comment: When I use suppress_filters it shows events from past. I think that this makes more damage than helps.